# Detect mouse back/forward button clicks

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In ActionScript 3, can I detect when the user has clicked their back or forward hardware buttons on their mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Doesn't look like it.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#constantSummary)

From what I can see you're able to work with:

- Scroll wheel.
- Middle click.
- Left click.
- Right click (AIR or Flash Player 11.2).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You can find a list of all supported events in the [`MouseEvent` documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#summaryTableConstant).